# Best practices Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have been trying Vue.js with ASP.Net Core for the last week and it seems quite powerful.
However, I have seen different approaches in the way how files are organized and modules written.

In the [javascript spatemplate](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/templates), they use, I would say this structure with ts, html, css files:

```
|_components
  |_counter
    *counter.ts
    *counter.css
    *counter.html
```

In other starter Vue.js templates, we have this structure with one single vue file:

```
|_components
  |_counter.vue
```

Is there a limitation/advantage in using one over the other? Is one being more recent and should superseed the other format?

I have also see that they are different way of writing component for Vue in Typescript.

The default one presented on the Vue website and the other way using the [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) or the [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) which looks more natural to me and is recommended on the Vue website as it seems to solve some issues: [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components).

Again if it is that good, why shouldn't it become the standard? Does the default style gives more flexibility compared with the 'vue-class-component' style?

Sorry for the basic questions, just trying to get the good directions from the beginning.

Comment: The advantage of single file components (the .vue file) is that *all* the code for the component is in *one* file. You don't have to be shuffling from file to file to make changes to your component; it's all in one place. The SPA template for core seems to be set up more to play nicely with Typescript, which isn't a main concern for most of the Vue community. I prefer the starter laid out on the [Typescript site](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter#typescript-vue-starter) but you would likely have to make it play with spa services yourself.